# Is it possible to craft an item that provides a skill bonus to Spellcraft?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

In Pathfinder, is it possible to create an item using the Craft Wondrous Item feat, that provides a skill bonus to Spellcraft for creating magic items?

What would be the most appropriate item and cost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course!

Usually such magic items would confer a competence bonus to said skill.  For crafting stuff, I would suggest either gloves, head, or ring slot, but that's what makes sense to me (and if you're looking for suggestions for your GM, he/she may have their own opinions).

As far as cost goes, I think 2,000 gp to 5,000 gp would be appropriate assuming it only applies to Spellcraft for creating magic items (versus say identifying a spell).

Example of a magic item granting craft skill bonuses:  [Ring of Maniacal Devices](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-maniacal-devices)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The general crafting costs for a wondrous item granting a skill bonus would be determined by this formula: "Bonus squared x 100 gp" (Source: [Table-Estimating-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#Table-Estimating-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values)). So for a +5 item that'll be around 2500 Gold. Of course, if @borro wants to limit it to only creating magic items, I'd add a discount of about 20% - 40%.

Answer (score 2):

### There is a published amulet that does this

The [Armillary Amulet](https://aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Armillary%20Amulet) published in the [Pathfinder Module: From Shore to Sea](https://paizo.com/products/btpy8evj)

> The amulet grants its wearer a +5 competence bonus on Spellcraft checks

Being a magic item from a module, you may want to check with your GM if the item is allowed.